# Are "will this party work" questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions

I want to ask a question about a party. I'm GMing and I want to know if a campaign a particular set of characters would be too hard to run: we are only 4 people (so 3 PCs) and they all want to be a support class. I want to know how to deal with that (so Asking what challenges to use in my adventures, for example). Can I ask a question like this?

Comment: Can you provide more detail, especially what you mean by "work" and "too hard"?

Comment: Sure, wait a second while I edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say so, but you're going to want to be as specific as you can be. Things like:

1. What classes specifically are they using?
2. What problems are you expecting that to cause?
3. What adjustments, if any, have you already made?

If it's just a vague concern about unspecified classes, it's pretty hard to answer. If it's a specific concern about specific classes, someone can probably answer how to mitigate that.

Comment: As an addition to this answer, asking a vague 'what challenges can I use' as a general open question probably wouldn't be OK, but giving party details and offering a specific challenge for people to critique would

Comment: Also, you would need to define success criteria.  Some GM's consider a 50% casualty rate acceptable, others wouldn't dream of it.

Comment: I don't know - "will this work," "is this too hard," all signs that someone needs to figure out how to ask a not purely opinion question.  Technically yes, questions about a given party's strengths and flaws or combat efficiency are OK but not when stated in this way without clear requirements.